# Property as a decorator in Python 2.4?

Tags: python

I'm developing an application for someone who is tied down to Python 2.4. According to the Python builtins page's description of [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) that "the `getter`, `setter`, and `deleter` attributes were added" in Python 2.6. Is there still a way to use property as a decorator, or is it imperative to use the `x = property(...)` syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use it as a decorator, but you can *only* specify a getter if you do so. You can delete the getter, setter, and deleter methods once you have called `property()` though.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried deleting the accessors (working in Python 2.7 and hoping it would be right for 2.4) but in my tests I had forgotten to inherent from `object` so I couldn't figure it out. :( Working now.